# How to get a list of all table available in the db?

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net

My goal is get the name of all table from my database and put it on my ComboBox. I hadn't used vb.net from years and now I'm dusting off a bit 'of stuff, but I need help because I don't come out. This is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class DataIn

Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim myData As New DataTable
Dim SQL As String

Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection

Private Sub DataIn_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()

    'Connection String
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;" _
    & "user id=root;" _
    & "password=123456789;" _
    & "database=calendario"

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()

        SQL = "SELECT name FROM calendario.tables"
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        myAdapter.Fill(myData)
        ComboBox1.Items = myData

    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Connection failed: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

I got this message:

> Table 'calendario.tables' doesn't exists

What am I doing wrong? 
Also I want to know how I can encrypt the connection details hard-coded in `ConnectionString` 'cause in the future this application must be distributed to my customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use query

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'
```

or

```
USE YOURDBNAME
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

and also change your `ComboBox1.Items = myData` to

```
  For intcount=0 to mydata.rows.count-1
     comboBox1.Items.Add(mydata.rows(intcount).item(0))
   Next
```

hope that helps..

Comment: Now I get another error on:  ComboBox1.Items = myData, said property Items is readonly

Comment: change combobox.items to combobox.datasource

Comment: Okay but now in the Combobox instead of the name of the table I get: System.Data.DataRowView why?

Comment: Okay I've used your code and I also added .Reset for delete all data from the object myData previously used. Thank you, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

mysql query,

```
SELECT table_name, table_type, engine FROM information_schema.tables
```